# try to compiling project with qt creator and Tmx parser

Tags: c++, makefile, qmake, tmx

i can't compile project with qt creator, this throw the next error

```
:-1: error: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0/../../../../lib/libtmxparser.a(TmxLayer.o): undefined reference to symbol 'uncompress'

/usr/lib/libz.so:-1: error: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

but i added the libraries to .pro file

```
LIBS += -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -ltinyxml -lz -ltmxparser
```

i can compile this project with makefile but no with qt creator and qmake

Comment: Try placing the `-lz` after `-ltmxparser`.

Comment: well this is embarrassing. -ltmxparser needs to be before -lz and -ltinyxml.

Comment: Thank you Joachim Pileborg. I wasted so much time in try to compiling this with qt creator

Comment: If you want to know the reason, it's because the linker looks for dependencies in the order they come on the command line. So when you have `-lz` before anything depending on the z library, then the library is simply discarded. So later when there *is* a dependency the linker will not scan the z library again.

Comment: Thank you. But curiously this order works with make, but no with qmake

Comment: If you write the answer as an answer instead of a comment, the question can be marked as answered, thanks!